# What is base of $\log$ in Subexponential Algo for DLP?

Tags: discrete-logarithm, factoring

I am currently going through this paper - ["A Subexponential Algorithm for the Discrete Logarithm Problem"](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=4568001) by Leonard Adleman.

On page 56, author mentions that Dixon's algorithm - [Asymptotically Fast Factorization of Integers](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1981-36-153/S0025-5718-1981-0595059-1/S0025-5718-1981-0595059-1.pdf), works in $RTIME (O(2^{O{(\log(q)\log\log(q))}^{1/2}}))$ and on page57, mentions that $r_i, s_i$ are smooth with respect to bound $2^{c ({\log(q)\log\log(q)})^{1/2}}$ .

My question is are these logs mentioned in equation, base $e$ or $2$? Because in [his paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1981-36-153/S0025-5718-1981-0595059-1/S0025-5718-1981-0595059-1.pdf) (on page 255), Dixon has mentioned the complexity equation in $\ln$ which means natural log, i.e. base $e$.

Comment: It's definitely not base 10. ​ The question should've been whether they're base e or 2. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17396819/1285942) starting at "However, note..."

Comment: See also [this](https://www.quora.com/Why-we-do-not-consider-base-of-log-in-time-complexity?share=1)

Comment: @mikeazo : ​ It _does_ matter here, since these logs are in the exponent. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer: nope, they don't, because they're either in a $O(\textit{formula})$ notation, or multiplied by an unspecified constant; either form eats constant factors

Comment: Oh, yeah. ​ ​ ​

Comment: Thanks for the links. Edited the question for 2 instead of 10. And I just read in D. Stinson book(Ed. 3, page 199 ), base for 2^{c ({log(q)loglog(q)})^{1/2}} is 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, the base does not matter as the $\log$ terms are wrapped in an $O$ expression. The $O$ expression lets you throw away constant factors and to convert something base $X$ to base $Y$ is simply $\log_X Z = \frac{\log_Y Z}{\log_Y X}$, well, $\log_Y X$ is a constant, so it can be thrown out in the $O$ expression.

The reason the second reference explicitly use $\ln$ is that the $O$ expression includes an exponent that does not also contain an $O$ expression. In this case, the base does matter.